Caching node_modules of yarn in GitLab CI
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test

variables:
  FF_USE_FAST_ZIP: 'true'
  ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: 'fast'
  CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: 'fast'

cache:
  paths:
    - .yarn
    - node_modules
  key:
    files:
      - yarn.lock
  untracked: true
  policy: pull

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - yarn install --immutable
  # artifacts:
  #   paths:
  #     - node_modules/
  #   expire_in: 1 day
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    policy: pull-push
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - .yarn
      - node_modules

build:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - packages/*/dist
    expire_in: 1 day
  script:
    - yarn build:remote-cache

check-dependencies:
  stage: test
  needs: [install]
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn dependsOnCheck
  dependencies: []

I'm trying to cache the node_modules in the Gitlab CI Pipeline, so that the node_modules is just one time installed.
But I receive this error the most time in my current configuration:
Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)
When I'm adding the artifacts to the install job, it works. But the downloading does take I want to save from the caching.
Not every time but mostly

did you find a solution?

No, didnt find one.
